# How to change css style by javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have css style

```
chosen-container b::after {
font-family: FontAwesome;
content: "\f078";
}
```

I need to change this attribute by java script to become:

```
chosen-container b::after {
font-family: FontAwesome;
content: "\f077";
```

Comment: Easiest way is to simply create a second class (for example, .chosen-container-toggled b::after { ... } ) and use javascript to toggle between the two.

Comment: You can't manipulate CSS styles directly using Javascript. In case you have such case where you want to change attributes of CSS , better to create two different css class and use them conditinally using jsvascript

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin

Answer (score 1):

Using plain vanilla Javascript , you can do this using the following code:

```
var cont = document.getElementByClassName(".chosen-container");
cont.className += " container-selected";
```

A better practice is to apply another modifier class to your element.

You are storing the chosen container as a variable and telling javascript to apply an additional class to it (`.container-selected`) or one of your choice.

Then simply apply the needed changes to that modifier class like so:

```
.chosen-container.container-selected b::after {
     font-family: 'FontAwesome';
     content: "\f077"; 
}
```

Therefore, javascript will look for that element, apply the new class with the updated icon to it and voila.